# Show that the sequence $5, 12, 19, 26, ...$ contains no terms of the form $2^n$ or $2^n-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the sequence $5, 12, 19, 26, ...$ contains no terms of the form $2^n$ or $2^n-1$.

I know that this is an arithmetic progression, $a_n=7n-2$. In order to show what is asked I tried setting $7n-2=2^n$ and $7n-2=2^n-1$ and tried to show that either no $n$ satisfies either equation or a contradiction arises, but I'm having a hard time. I have a feeling this problem is really simple too. For $7n-2=2^n$ I found that $n$ needs to be even and for $7n-2=2^n-1$ I found that $n$ needs to be odd. I also think that this approach might not be valid. Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are using $n$ for what could be two different quantities

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variable for both numbers. The equations you should have are $7n-2=2^m$ and $7n-2=2^m-1$

Comment: @jjagmath I was thinking this and that what I did would lead be all over the place and not be helpful.

Comment: You can also plot $2^n-7*n+2 , 2^n-1-7*n+2$,

Comment: You are mixing the two cases. Those are two separate equations.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for all $n$, $2^n$ must be equivalent to either $2$, $4$, or $1$ mod 7. This can be shown by induction on $n$.

And therefore, $2^n - 1$ is equivalent to either $1$, $3$, or $0$ mod 7.

But elements of the sequence $a$ are equal to $5$ mod 7. So $2^n$ and $2^n - 1$ can never be elements of this arithmetic sequence.

Comment: So this proves that no number in the sequence can have the form $2^n$ and $2^n-1$?

Comment: Because $2^n$ and $2^n-1$ are never congruent to $5$ (mod $7$)?

Comment: @ddswsd Exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider powers of $2 \bmod{7}$ (i.e. remainders when divided by $7$). What pattern do you notice?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing showing that the $n$th term isn't equal to the $n$th power of $2$ (or $1$ less).

That's not what's being asked. (And it's easy to show $7n -2 \ne 2^n$ or $2^n - 1$.)  You need to show that *no* term is equal to *any* power.

So you have to show that we can't ever have $7n -2 = 2^m$ nor $7n -2 = 2^m-1$ for any pair of $n, m$ which are not necessarily equal.

....

I'd note that $2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ if $m = 3k + i$ where $i = 0,1,2$ then $2^m=2^{3k+i} (2^3)^k2^i=8^k2^i\equiv 1\cdot 2^i\mod 7$.

So $2^m\equiv 1,2$ or $4\pmod 7$ and $2^m\not \equiv 0,3,5,6\pmod 7$.

And so $2^m = 7n-2\equiv 5\pmod 7$ is not possible.

Nor is $2^m - 1=7n -2\implies 2^m = 7n -1\equiv 6\pmod 7$.

(We can't have $7n-2\equiv 2^m-2$ or $7n-2\equiv 2^m-5$ either BTW).